# Vim error E886 and E509

Tags: vim, terminal

Whenever I :wq, I get to save and quit, but I get the following error:

> E886: Can't rename viminfo file to /Users/biona001/.viminfo! Press
>   ENTER or type command to continue

If I try to edit my ~/.bash_profile, it doesn't even let me save.

> "~/.bash_profile" E509: Cannot create backup file (add ! to override)
>   Press ENTER or type command to continue

Is there a solution? I assume it has something to do with my backup files

Comment: can you create a file in your home directory? `echo foo > ~/afile`. Probably a permissions problem on your homedir.

Comment: Oh I can't, dang.  Do you know how to fix this problem?

Comment: if you're at work, call your IT team. If you're root of your machine I suppose that `sudo chmod u+rwx /Users/biona001` would do it.

Comment: This is on my home computer, and your command doesn't seem to work. Thanks for you help though, I'll search around

Comment: I'm not a Linux expert. Can you edit your question to show the output of `ls -l /Users/biona001` ? I'm sure you'll get answers.

Comment: Actually I use a mac, and I have a ton of stuff in my home directory. Not sure if it'll help too much when I post those files/folders

Comment: sorry, I meant `sudo ls -l /Users`

Comment: nah, you meant `sudo ls -ld /Users/biona001` as it shows only the folder itself and not its content.